# jQuery animation code only running first instruction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm fairly certain I'm being massively stupid here, but how can I run multiple jQuery animation instructions one after the other. The code below causes my box to move away from the left hand side correctly, but does not cause it to expand down.

```
click : function(){
        $(this).not(".break").animate({left: '100%'}, 300);
        $(this).slideDown(300);
     },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split them into two:

```
$(this).not(".break").animate({left: '100%'}, 300);
$(this).children().slideDown(300).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't appear to be working... I used the complete callback code and I am getting the same results as before. Is it possible that the actual animations I'm trying to run aren't working?

Comment: Ugh. I feel like I've messed it up entirely now. It doesn't do anything anymore. Somehow I've got the wrong number of brackets. I've updated my code.

Comment: @Roboguy99, you left `.children()` part.

Comment: I know about that. I removed that as a test to see if that was the issue. It doesn't work with or without it. Also, I think it should be .show() on the end...